# data-dismiss and close button for notification bar

Tags: html, css

I have a notification bar on top of my site (before I had a modal).
Is it possible to click the X (close-button) and have the notification bar remove? I tried data-dismiss but that didnt work. And how to get the X button directly after my last work "END" with the same background-color as my text?
I use Bootstrap-3.

HTML

```
<div class="notification-bar">
    <div class="text">
        <p>laallalala l lalal lalalalalal lal lalal lal l allalalalalalalalallalalaalallalalalaalallalal l laallalal lal lall lalallalaallallalaalalaa END</p>
    </div>
        <button class="btn btn-close" data-dismiss="notification-bar" type="button">&times;</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.notification-bar {
    background-color:#003000;
}

.text {
    color:#5EFFEF;
    font-family:'Droid Serif';
    font-size:13px;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
}

.btn.btn-close {
    color:#5EFFEF;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

JSFIDDLE here... [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rabas007/0q8zu8tk/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achive this with jQuery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dismisbar").click(function(){
        $(".notification-bar").hide();
    }); 
});
</script>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32yo1qqk/)